# API response "Unsupported Media Type" in C#

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Following is my code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
var MemberIdDto = new StringContent(content, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic 123456789");
var response = client.PostAsync(URL, MemberIdDto).Result;
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

`content` contains json, I'm getting "Unsupported Media Type" in response. and `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` is false
I have tried to add

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

but still I'm getting the same response.
I also have tried using `application/text`, but it did not work
When I try this using Postman, it has worked properly.

Comment: Can you show your API too?

Comment: "Unsupported Media Type" literally means the server does not accept your JSON formatted content. Are you sure your server API accepts JSON (and not XML or something else)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove .Result from response
and add await  since you are using ReadAsStringAsync :

```
var response = client.PostAsync(URL, MemberIdDto);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

and I highly recommend you to add to your code:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```